# Using ArcPy to create Graduated Colours?

Tags: arcpy, symbology, arcgis-10.4

To preface this, I am using ArcMap 10.4.1, and currently new in using Arcpy and coding in general, so I am struggling on how to make my layer go from just simple point data, into graduated colour point data. The point data is just locations of cities and this point data was joined by a table that includes the city names too and additional information such as Age.

I am trying to automate this process, but I am unsure of what the coding sequence to actually turn the point data to a Graduated Colours symbology. Manually, I have no issues, but that is something I am trying to avoid. I've done some reading on this, but if I interepreted right         `arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management` is using a layer to create a symbology for another layer, not necessarily referring to graduated colours? I currently have this for my code which I used some code from other questions asked when I was searching for my answer. I may have found it already, but I may be interpreting things wrong.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "K:\GEOG 3P95\Final_proj\Workspace"
# get's the map document
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
#get the data frame(s)
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"*")[0]

# create a new layer and adds them on Top or Bottom
lake = arcpy.mapping.Layer("K:\GEOG 3P95\Final_proj\Workspace\ghy_000e06a_e.shp")
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, lake,"TOP")

municipal = arcpy.mapping.Layer("K:\GEOG 3P95\Final_proj\Workspace\BOUND_05.shp")
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, municipal,"BOTTOM")

city = arcpy.mapping.Layer("K:\GEOG 3P95\Final_proj\Workspace\Final_export_all_data.shp")
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, city,"TOP")


municipal = "BOUND_05"
city = "ONppn"
lake = "ghy_000e06a_e"
province = "province"

#Changes coordinate systems for the Municpal, Lake, Province and City Point layers, respectively.
coord_system = arcpy.SpatialReference('NAD 1983 UTM Zone 17N')
arcpy.Project_management("BOUND_05","BOUND_05_1983",coord_system)
arcpy.Project_management("ghy_000e06a_e","lake_1983",coord_system)
arcpy.Project_management("province","province_1983",coord_system)
arcpy.Project_management("Final_export_all_data","City_1983",coord_system)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had almost the same problem, but I had to make a symbology for unique values.
The first thing is to have a *.lyr file stored in certain folder. It should have the symbology referred to your feature layer you want to paint with symbology of lyr file.
When file is created, there goes the srcipt command which adds your lyr file to the TOC. Only after that you can change the symbology of your initaial layer. Just to have and order in your TOC lyr file can be removed.
Then you have your feature layer but probably without symbology because it has to keep the unique values, which can be different. Here you can also use scripts to have your symbology changed.

here is my example of code:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = mxd.activeDataFrame

#Add your lyr file

ary = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"\\Path to your symbology layer\file.lyr")
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer (df,ary,"AUTO_ARRANGE")



#Apply symbology

for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "",df):
     if lyr.name == "Your feature layer":
         arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management("Your feature layer","Symbology from lyr file")

#Remove symbology

for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "",df):
         if lyr.name == "Symbology from lyr file":
             arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df,lyr)

#Make your symbology looking like you have unique values in specific field

lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Your feature layer")[0]
if lyr.symbologyType == "UNIQUE_VALUES":
   lyr.symbology.valueField = "FIELD SYMBOLGY BASED ON"
   lyr.symbology.addAllValues()

arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

Comment: `for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "",df):
     if lyr.name == "Your feature layer":
         arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management("Your feature layer","Symbology from lyr file")` In regards to this line, do I have to have another layer that has my symbology? Can I not use the data from the actual layer? I joined a table to my layer so that I could manually create Graduated Colours Symbology, is this code not taking that into account?

Comment: According to my tests, symbology layers are not able apply for layers with joined table or other layer. Also lyr files can be made for the certain spatial type (lines, polygons or points) and if data from lyr file doesn't match the data in feature layer, script won't work.